# CSS: how to make a block element take as much width as its children require?

Tags: html, css

Due to my background with Linux 2D-graphics libraries, such as GTK+, where parent window typically requests as much space as its children need to display appropriately, I feel bad about the habit of block elements in CSS to take all the width of parent.

Is it possible to have a block element take width, determined by intrinsic widths of its children and not more?

Answer (score 5):

use `display: inline-block` on such container. it will preserve the `block` property without taking the full width of its container.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dekf0h3f/